# How to pass this through ng-click to an angular function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click, this

The items that has the ng-click is not part of a repeat loop. Below is the example of what I'm trying to do. How should I pass the caller element to the function?

`<div ng-click="myFunction(this)"></div>`

In my angular controller:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(elem){
  $(elem).addClass('newClass');
}
```

Comment: In angular you shouldn't have to worry about the element, rather focus on the scope model. What are you trying to do? Please show some of your code

Comment: give us some code example.

Comment: Just added the example.

Comment: `this` will not be the element (unlike the click event you register directly on a DOM element), scope has a property name this which points to itself, so ultimately `elem` will be scope. But as others mentioned this is not the right way to do. You just need an ngClass. `<div ng-click="myFunction(this)" ng-class="{'newCLass':canAddClass}"></div>` and in the ngCLick just set $scope.canAddClass = true

Comment: why dont you just use onclick if you're going to do this....

Comment: I'm trying to keep all my functions within the controller to keep the code clean.

Answer (score 1):

Probably could use ng-class for the use-case you are talking about (see above answer).  But to answer the original question about how to pass the element through the ng-click directive:

The ng-click directive allows you to pass $event object

```
<div ng-click="myFunction($event)"></div>
```

The $event object is essentially a jquery event object so you can extract not only information about the event, but also about the elements involved in it and their parents/children.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this solution**

> 1. in AngularJS Use : (***$event***) instead of (***this***).
> 2. (***angular.element***) is the JQuery(***$***).
> 3. (***.target***) is the [***HtmlElementObject***]

```js
// MODULE
        var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

        MyApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.ShowEnteredName = function (objSender) {

               alert(angular.element(objSender.target).next("input[type=text]").val());

            };

        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>



<div id="div_Container" data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-controller="MainController">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-ng-click="ShowEnteredName($event)">Click Me</a>
<input type="text" ID="txtName" Value=""/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs, you don't need to operate DOM. If you want to add a class to any items, just use angular way:

```
<div ng-click="addClass('newclass')" ng-class='myclass'></div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.addClass = function(newclass){
  $scope.myclass = $scope.myclass + ' ' + newclass;
}
```

When `$scope.myclass` changed, `ng-class` would auto refresh.